# Simplify if statement - Angular

Tags: typescript, if-statement

Is there a way to simplify this If statement? All variables are strings and I reuse them in both but depending if it returns `true` or `false`.

```
if(params.province && !params.streetType && !params.streetNr){
  this.localityIdCP = params.localityId;
}

if(params.province && params.streetType && !params.streetNr){
  this.streetIdCP = params.localityId;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
if(params.province && !params.streetNr){
  if(params.streetType) {
    this.streetIdCP = params.localityId;
  }else {
    this.localityIdCP = params.localityId;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate the mandate values and hold the result in a temporary variable, which is then used in the subsequent place where you have to repeat code

```
const _result = (params.province && !params.streetNr);
this.localityIdCP = _result && !params.streetType && params.localityId;
this.streetIdCP = _result && params.streetType && params.localityId;
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [the conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/conditional-operator-q?view=vs-2019) inside a if statement

```
if(params.province && !params.streetNr){
  params.streetType ? this.streetIdCP = params.localityId : this.localityIdCP = params.localityId;
}
```